# How can I use a d3 library (like c3.js) on the server side to generate charts in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I'm trying to generate charts using c3js, which is a d3 library for easier charting.

I see that you can use plain d3 to generate charts on the server side using jsdom since there is an npm module for d3. This is the guide I was following for that process: http://www.gregjopa.com/2013/11/render-svg-charts-server-side-with-d3-js/

However, there is no npm module for nvd3 or c3js.

How can I use these libraries on the server side to generate charts for use on the client side?

Comment: `npm install c3` I don't work with this library but I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This sounds like a question to ask the c3js or nvd3 developers…

Answer (score 1):

One library that does have a Node.js build is [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com). Trying the library is free, however the Node build is for licensed customers. Full disclosure, I'm on the ZingChart team. However if you'd like more info, feel free to reach out.